# 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll'

Tags: c#, interop

Why get an error:

```
'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
```

here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MacierzeJacobiego
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Go under the DEBUG menu, select "Exceptions", and from the dialog that comes up, place a check box in the "Thrown" column for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". Click OK, and then try debugging again.

Execution will stop where the exception occurs.

Cheers

Comment: I'm having the same issue, tried this, and it stopped in the same place without telling me anything new.

Comment: @F1Krazy: you do realize that this is a 6 years old question? You didn't think to ask for further information before giving downvoting my answer? The original user seems to have found the answer useful, so would you mind explaining the rationale behind your downvote? Thanks